# React Testing Library functional test to start another Cypress test

Tags: cypress, react-testing-library

Perhaps a rather poor setup, but something I learned in part from the first [TDD book](https://obeythetestinggoat.com) I read.

Is it possible to have a large RTL `functional.test.tsx` that basically runs through a user story firing off a bunch of other tests and/or commands?

Specifically would this work or be ideal:

functional.test.tsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from '../testUtils'
import { Home } from '../../pages/index'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'

//TDD Books: User Story
describe('Home page', () => {
  //Bob logs into TDD Books using Google (or Github).
  test('login works', () => {
   
     *** run: cypress run --spec "cypress/integration/login.js" ***
     expect(cypress_login).toBe('passed')         
  
  })  

  //Bob can see either his book shelf he added from earlier or it's empty waiting for books to be added.

   ...
```

I'm on this train of thread because NextAuth.js [recommends](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/testing-with-cypress) using Cypress for testing social logins.

Comment: Probably can do it if you invert the frameworks, i.e Cypress calls [cypress-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/cypress-testing-library). The way you are working you'd need to use `execa` to invoke cypress run, and save the login to a file - all sorts of bothersome stuff.

Comment: Having said that, what does `cypress/integration/login.js` do? Maybe you can reproduce it in Jest and ditch the Cypress part?

Comment: It’s as demo’ed here: https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/testing-with-cypress